# prove that determinant is a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

let $V$ be a vector space of all $2 \times 2$ hermitian matrices with entries from $\mathbb C$, over the field $\mathbb R$.
prove that $q(v)=\det(v)$ is a quadratic form.

I tried to prove that $f(u,v)=$$1\over4$$(q(u+v)-q(u-v))$ is a bilinear form but i'm stuck with that... can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What's your definition of quadratic form? One solution might be to observe that an explicit formula for $\det(v)$ is a homogeneous quadratic polynomial in the entries of $v$.

Comment: my definition:
$q(v)$ is a quadratic form if there exists a symmetric bilinear form $f:V \times V \to F$ such that $q(v) = f(v,v)$.
I didn't quite understand your suggestion though...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$\det\pmatrix{x&z+wi\\ z-wi&y}=xy - z^2 - w^2=
\pmatrix{x&y&z&w}\pmatrix{0&\tfrac12&0&0\\ \tfrac12&0&0&0\\ 0&0&-1&0\\ 0&0&0&-1}\pmatrix{x\\ y\\ z\\ w}.$$

Comment: didn't think about looking at the matrix defining $f$ at all! thanks!

Comment: though I think there is a little mistake in your answer. $V$ is over the field $\mathbb R$, therefore $x$ and $y$ both need to be represented by 2 element from the basis (unlike the other 2 entries which go together, both of which need are represented by 2 element from the basis). So $dim(V) = 6$, there for $f$ needs to be a $6 \times 6$ matrix, and the vectors need to be of size 6 too. But thanks for giving me the direction!

Comment: @izikgo The matrices are Hermitian, so the diagonal entries must be real. You may of course embed the 4-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-linear space of Hermitian matrices into the 6-dimensional space of complex matrices, but this is not necessary. In case you need the embedding. The matrix representation of the quadratic is permutation-similar to the direct sum of the present one with a $2\times2$ zero block.

Comment: yeah i realized that after I commented that hermitian matrix enforce the diagonal to be real... thanks!

Comment: So I have another follow-up question that i'm strugelling with: If I can show that $1 \over 4$$(q(u+v)-q(u-v))$ is symmetric (meaning I can swap $u$ and $v$ and the result is the same) for any given $q(v): V \to F$, does that necessarily mean that $q$ is a quadratic form?

Comment: @izikgo No. $q(x)=\|x\|_2^2+1$ is not a quadratic form, but $\frac14\left(q(u+v)-q(u-v)\right)$ is symmetric in $u$ and $v$.