# Determinant of a symmetric matrix a quadratic form proof

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be the vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ of $2\times 2$ real symmetric matrices.
> Show that the function $f$ on $V$ such that $f(A)=\det(A)$ is a quadratic form.

Itried to solve this question in the following way:

A quadratic form is defined as $g(v,v)=f(v)$ in which $g$ is a bilinear form.
$f:V\to \mathbb{R}$

I tried to use the bilinear form definition:

> Let K be a field and $V,W$ vector spaces over $K$. A map $g:V\times W\to K$ is said to be bilinear if it satisfies the following properties:
>
> BI 1. For all $v_1,v_2\in V$ and $w\in W$ we have
>
> $g(v_1+v_2,w)=g(v_1,w)+g(v_2,w)$
>
> and for all $v\in V$ and $w_1,w_2\in W$ we have
>
> $g(v,w_1+w_2)=g(v,w_1)+g(v,w_2)$
>
> BI 2. For all $c\in K$,$v\in V$ and $w\in W$,
>
> $g(cv,w)=cg(v,w)=g(v,cw)$.

Taking the example $A=\begin{bmatrix}x&y\\y&z\end{bmatrix}$

$f(cA)=cxcz-cycy=c^2(xz-y^2)=c^2f(A)\neq cf(A)$

**Question**:

**1)** What is wrong with my attempt of proof?

**2)** How can I prove $\det(A)$ is a quadratic form?

Comment: You could just write down the determinant.

Comment: look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386848/prove-that-determinant-is-a-quadratic-form?rq=1

Comment: $\det(A)=xz-yy=xz-y^2$

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks I think it helps. What about my attempt of proof?

Comment: The usual phrasing is to say that it is a quadratic form in the entries of the symmetric matrix.

Comment: @WillJagy                                  $\begin{bmatrix}x&y&z\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\0&-1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @WillJagy Is this enough to prove the statement?

Comment: It would be if your matrix were symmetric. Maybe you just mistyped because it is in a comment box. My impression is that you are studying on your own. What book are you using, or  online notes?

Comment: @WillJagy            Yes I am studying on my own. I am reading Lang´s Linear Algebra. How do I get it to be symmetric?

Comment: @WillJagy              I was using the following matrix to get the quadratic form $\begin{bmatrix}0&-y&z\end{bmatrix}$, once $\begin{bmatrix}0&-y&z\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\-y\\z\end{bmatrix}=xz-y^2=\det(A)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a quadratic form over the real numbers, in finite dimension, the matrix is **half the Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives**. This time

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

You should (carefully) do the multiplication

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
x & y & z \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
x \\ y \\ z 
\end{array}
\right)
$$